# How to make an element with fluid width be a circle

Tags: html, css

I have some `div`s containing texts. I want them to be circles, and the text should fit inside them.

I tried setting the `border-radius` property to `50%`, but

- They became ovals since the `width` is in `%` and varies based on the viewport, so I cannot make its `height` to be the same amount.
- The text may overflow the oval.

```html
<div class="col3">
    Some content
</div>
```

```css
.col3 {
    background-color: #3cb371;
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 30%;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b2Uan/)

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this trick to get a 1:1 ratio:

```
<div class="circle">
    <div class="content">
        Some content
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.circle {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #3cb371;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 30%;
}
.circle:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%; /* 1:1 ratio */
}
.content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2nD9/)

Or, if you want to force the text to be inside the circle,

```css
.content {
    top: 15%; right: 15%; bottom: 15%; left: 15%;
}
```

Where `15%` is an approximation of `(1-Math.cos(Math.PI/4))/2*100`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/v2nD9/1/)

Comment: The text is outside the circle in the fiddle. I believe OP wants it inside the circle.

Comment: @Lynda work fine in Firefox and Chrome. +1 Oriol! Great answer

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - First time I looked it wasn't working. It is working now.

Comment: Why `-2` for my question posted?

Comment: @Pradeep Probably, people downvoted the question because you didn't include your code in the question itself.